# How to get sound to start only after text to speech ends

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, text-to-speech

I have this code which reads a string using text to speech and then plays a sound. However, the sound plays at the same time that the text to speech is used. I tried to use onutterancecompletedlistener and onutteranceprogresslistener but now when I run the code, only the text to speech is heard and not the sound. Am I implementing something incorrectly? Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!!

```
String animalString = res.getString(R.string.Animal);
                tv.setText(animalString);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    tts.speak(greenString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId)
                        {
                            sound.start();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    tts.speak(greenString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
                        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

                                sound.start();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Comment: You need to use the API correctly, a clue would be passing in `null` parameters. There are plenty of examples out there. You need to pass in an utterance id.

Comment: @brandall How do I pass in an utterance id? I can't find any examples.